# Why am I getting the error "model not found : product.print.zpl.barcode" when I try to install a module?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to install my custom module `product_print_zpl_barcode`, but when I press the button install it shows this error:

```
ParseError: "Invalid view definition

D\xe9tails de l'erreur :
Mod\xe8le non trouv\xe9 : product.print.zpl.barcode

Contexte de l'erreur :
Vue `product_print_zpl_barcode.form`
[view_id: 847, xml_id: n/a, model: product.print.zpl.barcode, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing [...]/openerp/addons/product_print_zpl_barcode/views/product_print_zpl_barcode_view.xml:5, near
```

### `product_print_zpl_barcode_view.xml`

```
<record id="product_print_zpl_barcode_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product_print_zpl_barcode.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.print.zpl.barcode</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Generate and Print Product Barcode">
            <group name="step1" string="Configuration">
                <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <field name="product_name" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'step2')]}"/>
                <field name="pricelist_id" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'step2')]}"/>
                <field name="price_uom"/>
                <field name="label_size" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'step2')]}"/>
                <field name="nomenclature_id" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'step2')]}"/>
                <field name="rule_id"/>
                <field name="barcode_type"/>
                <field name="barcode"/>
                <field name="copies" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'step2')]}"/>
            </group>
            <group string="Enter Quantity" attrs="{'invisible': [('barcode_type', '=', 'product')]}">
                <div name="qty_uom">
                    <field name="quantity" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'step2')]}" class="oe_inline"/>
                    <field name="uom_id" class="oe_inline"/>
                </div>
            </group>
            <group name="step2" states="step2" string="Label">
                <field name="price"/>
                <field name="zpl_file" filename="zpl_filename"/>
                <field name="zpl_filename" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="zpl_printer_id" required="1"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="generate" type="object" string="Generate Label" class="btn-primary" states="step1"/>
                <button special="cancel" string="Cancel" class="oe_link" states="step1"/>
                <button name="print_zpl" type="object" string="Print" class="btn-primary" states="step2"/>
                <button name="print_zpl" type="object" string="Print and New" class="btn-primary" context="{'print_and_new': True}" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('state', '!=', 'step2'), ('barcode_type', '=', 'product')]}"/>
                <button special="cancel" string="Close" class="oe_link" states="step2"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="product_print_zpl_barcode_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Generate Barcode</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.print.zpl.barcode</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

I want to create a new model `product.print.zpl.barcode` but Odoo doesn't recognize the new model even though the action is created.
Here is the code of

Comment: Have you created the model on the python side?

Comment: how to create it on the python side ?? because this error shows every time i want to create a new model

Comment: Please read the [Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#creating-models)

Comment: product_print_zpl_barcode.py existe with _name=''product.print.zpl.barcode' but always the same error      class ProductPrintZplBarcode(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'product.print.zpl.barcode'
    _description = 'Generate and print product barcodes in ZPL'

Comment: Are you adding the `import model_file` to the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: yes "from. import models" __init__.py and in the folder models (__init__.py)" from . import product_print_zpl_barcode"

Comment: it ok i restart the service and it works

Comment: OK, check my answer for more details. Mark as correct if it is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So make sure you are adding the model in the [right way](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#creating-models). You must take into account

- Include this in the `/your_module/__init__.py`

  ```
  import models
  ```
- Include this in the `/your_module/models/__init__.py`

  ```
  import model_name
  ```
- Include your model in the `/your_module/models/model_name.py` file:

  ```
  from openerp import models, fields


  class YourModel(models.Model):
      _name = 'a.model.name'

      field1 = fields.Char()
  ```
- To reload the python files you need to restart the server
- To reload the xml files you need to restart the service with the parameter `--update=your_module`. You can make this update by pressing the **Update** button on the module form.

**Note**: Take that if you inherit from the class `models.TransientModel` the data of your table is going to be erased from time to time. The common use is on wizards. If you want a persistent model you need to inherit from `models.Model`

Comment: @Dhouha Marks the answer as correct or vote it if it was useful, please. Thanks